# Somar sequência de números em Javascript

Tags: javascript, matemática

Vamos supor que o usuário digite o valor 40391, então eu preciso somar incrementalmente todos os valores de 1 até 40390, o que resulta no valor 815696245.

Hoje faço isso com um simples `for` mas percebi que a performance não é das melhores... Existe alguma forma de deixar isso mais performático ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, basta usar uma fórmula.

```
resultado = n(n+1)/2
```

Veja funcionando:

```js
var num = 40391;
var res = (num * (num - 1))/2; /*  adaptado o "-1" para o enunciado da pergunta  */
                               /*  que diz que input 40391 resulta em 815696245  */

document.write(res);
```

De curiosidade, esta sequência gera o que chamamos de "número triangular":

[image: Ilustração dos números triangulares]

Leitura complementar:

> https://oeis.org/A000217

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number